# Button not taking me to another page when I put it inside form

Tags: html, css

**body**

```
        <div class="container" style="margin-top: 70px;">
          <form>
            <div class="formcreate bg-light bg-gradient shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 bg-body rounded col-8">
                <div class="position-relative m-4">
                    <div class="progress" style="height: 1px;">
                      <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="position-absolute top-0 start-0 translate-middle btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-pill" style="width: 2rem; height:2rem;">1</button>
                    <button type="button" class="position-absolute top-0 start-50 translate-middle btn btn-sm btn-secondary rounded-pill" style="width: 2rem; height:2rem;">2</button>
                    <button type="button" class="position-absolute top-0 start-100 translate-middle btn btn-sm btn-secondary rounded-pill" style="width: 2rem; height:2rem;">3</button>
                  </div>
                <p id="signText"> Signup Form</p>
                <div class="row g-3">
                    <div class="col">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" aria-label="First name" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" aria-label="Last name" >
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row g-3">
                    <div class="col">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control passwordPov" placeholder="Password" aria-label="Password" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                      <input type="password" class="form-control passwordPov" placeholder="Retype Password" aria-label="RetypePassword" >
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label"></label>
                    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
                    <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
                  </div>
                  <a href="file:///C:/Users/okazi/Desktop/Website/Html/createaccountPageStepTwo.html">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success buttonPos">Continue</button>
                </a>
              </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I try to use Button Outside the Form Tag (`<form></form>`) nothing happens, but when I try to put it inside, it takes me to another page without any problem. I need the button inside the form to use (`required`) code.

Comment: Your question is unclear!

Comment: I mean You can see my page in (thekazim.tech/createaccountPage.php)
when you try to press continue it must to take you to another page but it doesn't
```<form>
<a herf="example.com">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success buttonPos">Continue</button>
</a>
</form>```
so I tried to to remove the ```<form>``` and it works but I need to put the ```<form>```

I hope that you understand

Comment: Links cannot contain `button` or `input` elements, it's invalid HTML.

Comment: change button type, maybe fixed!

Comment: it works but the problem is ```required``` code can be use inly for submit type

Comment: God, don't use absolute paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the button outside the for and make id for the form like this :

```
<form id="createForm">
</form>
```

and then but it inside the button like this :

```
<button form="createForm" type="submit">Next</button>
```

Also you can do another way

```
<form action="index.html">
<button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```